# batch script to kill process if still running after a certain time

Tags: batch-file, kill-process

I need to create a batch script that launches a program, and waits for up to 1 minute for the program to finish, and then do something else. The exact steps are:

1. Launch program A
2. Wait for program A to finish OR kill it if not finished within 1 minute.
3. Launch program B

To emphasise, in step 2, I do not want to wait for the full 1 minute if program A is finished within say, 5 seconds.

Comment: Sounds like a "do it for me" question. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm having trouble with Step 2. I know I can set a hard wait with the 'timeout' command, but can't progress further than that.

Comment: Edit the current (relevant) script your working with into your question for us to have a look at

Comment: Not sure how to script step 2, hence asking the question. Step 1 and 3 will probably be 'start program.exe'

Comment: Is program A a separate file, or part of the original batch script?

Comment: Program A is a separate file.

Comment: Will program A automatically terminate itself when finished?

Comment: Yes, program A will automatically terminate itself when finished.